# Three.js - object.visible = true, not showing up right away

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm hiding and unhiding parts of my Three.js scene using the `.visible` property on my objects.

By default certain objects (rooms) have the `.visible` property to `false`. When the camera is within a certain mesh (the room bounding box) the `.visible` property is set to `true` and the room shows up.

But there seems to be a delay (seconds or less) after setting the `.visible` property to `true` and the room actually being rendered. This delay is shortened after entering the rooms more than once.

What is the cause of this delay? Is there a way to know when or if the room is ready for rendering? It doesn't seem like update events are being fired after setting the `.visible` property to `true`, so listening for those won't help.

I appreciate any help,

Greets!

**EDIT**

Because I couldn't use `ColladaLoader2.js` I decided to simply traverse the models loaded with the `ColladaLoader.js` and replace all geometry properties with a `BufferGeometry` copy made from the existing `Geometry` object. After that I found out that setting the `.dynamic` property of an existing `Geometry` object to false seems to have the same effect.

`dae.traverse(function (obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty('geometry')) {
        obj.dynamic = false;
        //obj.geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().fromGeometry(obj.geometry);
    }
});`

Now when I set the object's `.visible` property to `true` the engine freezes for a little while, instead of the earlier mentioned delay before the object becomes visible. For now I'll have to decide where I want to little freeze to occur, because I don't think all objects can be visible at the same time for performance reasons.

It would be nice to have more control and information about if an object and it's geometry is loaded and ready to be viewed, or if it needs to be reloaded into memory. Now it's unclear if a `BufferGeometry` will show up immediately when `.visible` is set to `true` or a short freeze will occur.

Comment: Are you using `Geometry` or `BufferGeometry`?

Comment: I'm using ColladaLoader.js which seems to use `THREE.Geometry`. I downloaded the latest Three.js release and found ColladaLoader2.js which instead uses `THREE.BufferGeometry`. I'm going to test if using this loader fixes the delay problem.

Comment: My posted answer is the answer to your original question. Yes, ColladaLoader needs to be improved, and the new loader is a step in the right direction. Your testing of it is welcomed. : - )

Comment: I had to update my version of Three.js for `ColladaLoader2.js` to run and it still surprised me with a beautiful colourful scene where my objects were all over the place and textures weren't used only colors :D I think it needs the `convertUpAxis` option implemented and I guess there's something with the materials.

Comment: Then use the work-around in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Geometry` needs to be converted to `BufferGeometry` prior to rendering. This conversion will not occur if `mesh.visible` is `false`. The conversion can take some time if your geometries are complex, or if there are a lot of geometries to convert.

A work-around is to create your meshes using `BufferGeometry`.

```
var bufferGeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().fromGeometry( geometry );
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( bufferGeometry, material );
```

three.js r.73

Answer (score 0):

In my code I see the same thing when objects are first switched to visible, but subsequent switches between visible true/false do not seem to cause another delay.

Hence one workround would be to set the visible flag on every object and render everything when WebGLRenderer is not shown on the browser (e.g. when it is behind a level loading screen) then set the objects visible flags appropriately to how you want them prior to showing the screen... Now there should be no delay as you toggle them visible.