# mesh.visible property only updates 'false' (and only on screen)

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to constantly check if the distance between the two end vertices of each line mesh in a THREE.Group is below a certain threshold.

If it's below, I want to show the line and update the locations.

If it's beyond, I want to hide it temporarily. The idea is that as the vertices float around, the lines will 'attach' and 'detach' as they come near.

Here's an example of my approach:

```
function render(){
    renderer.render(scene,camera);
}
function animate(){
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    for(var i = 0; i < Lines.children.length; i++){
        var line = Lines.children[i];
        var dist = line.geometry.vertices[0].distanceTo( line.geometry.vertices[1] ));
        if( dist < tolerance ){
            line.visible = true;
            updateLineLoc(line);
        } else {
            line.visible = false;
        }
    }
    render();
}
animate();
```

Currently, the lines 'only' hide. When I've checked the mesh objects visible property, it 'never' changes, yet lines become un-visible.

In case the async is the problem I've tried putting the update calculations in a callback, as well as the per-frame render. I've checked to make sure my loop is still accessing the 'un-visible' ones, and I've triple checked that the distance calculation is solid. I've tried:

```
function goodDist( line, callback ){
    line.visible = true;
}
function animate(){
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    for(var i = 0; i < Lines.children.length; i++){
        var line = Lines.children[i];
        var dist = line.geometry.vertices[0].distanceTo( line.geometry.vertices[1] ));
        if( dist < tolerance ){
            line.visible = true;
            goodDist( line, updateLineLoc(line) );
        } else {
            line.visible = false;
        }
    }
    render();
}
animate();
```

and this:

```
function render(){
    renderer.render(scene,camera);
}
function checkNear(callback){
    for(var i = 0; i < Lines.children.length; i++){
        var line = Lines.children[i];
        var dist = line.geometry.vertices[0].distanceTo( line.geometry.vertices[1] ));
        if( dist < tolerance ){
            line.visible = true;
            updateLineLoc(line);
        } else {
            line.visible = false;
        }
    }
}
function animate(){
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    checkNear(render());
}
animate();
```

This is different from [Three.js - object.visible = true, not showing up right away](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34616054/three-js-object-visible-true-not-showing-up-right-away) because my meshes simply won't show up at all, not just load slowly. The state itself seems not to change. I can't seem to find an update flag for updating the visible property, but again, they're updating into the 'off' state (on screen at least).

One complication here is that I am using a custom shaderMaterial for the lines. I'm not sure if that could be responsible, but all its doing is interpolating between the colors of the vertexes.

Please help! :O

Comment: Can you post a live example in http://jsfiddle.net/ ? It sounds similar to a vertex winding order issue when you call `updateLineLoc()`, but not sure if your "Lines" are truly a `Line` object, or another type of geometry. I'd need to see it in action to be certain.